# java thread events notification

Tags: java, multithreading

I have got the below java gaming application (uses java8) code which runs in multi-threaded environment:

**Position class:**

```
 public class Position {

      private final String name;

      public Position(String name) {
        this.name = name;
      }

      public String getName() {
        return name;
      }

      public synchronized boolean acquire() {
        boolean positionStatus = false;
        //some business logic goes here to check if positionStatus can be made to true
        positionStatus = true;

        return positionStatus;
      }

      public synchronized boolean release() {
       //release code
       return true;
     }
    }
```

**Customer class:**

```
 import java.util.ArrayList;
 import java.util.List;

    public class Icon extends Thread {

  private String name;

  private List<Position> positions = new ArrayList<>();

  public Customer(String name, List<Icon> positions) {
    this.name = name;
    this.positions = positions;
  }

  @Override
  public void run() {
    try {
      for(Position position : positions) {
        if (position.acquire()) {
          //some business logic goes here
          System.out.println("position acquired :"+name);
        } else {
          System.out.println("position not available **** ");
        }
      }
    } catch(Exception exe) {
      System.out.println(exe);
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<Position> positions = new ArrayList<>();
    positions.add(new Position("Position1"));
    positions.add(new Position("Position2"));
    positions.add(new Position("Position3"));
    positions.add(new Position("Position4"));    

    Icon icon1 = new Icon("icon1", positions);
    Icon icon2 = new Icon("icon2", positions);
    Icon icon3 = new Icon("icon3", positions);
    Icon icon4 = new Icon("icon4", positions);

    icon1.start();
    icon2.start();
    icon3.start();
    icon4.start();
  }
}
```

My requirement is to move multiple icons at the same time to different locations, so I can't restrict the serialized access to Icon.

Basically, I have got a fixed list of Positions for each Icon and I am trying to acquire each 'Position' for the Icon.

Now, How can I ensure Icon1 acquiring Position1, Position2, Position3, Position4 first followed by Icon2 (should pick Position1 as soon as Icon1 completes Position1) and then followed by Icon3 etc..

I don't want to use the Thread join as it makes Icon2 to wait until Icon1 completes acquiring entire list of Positions.
Rather I need Icon2 to be acquiring Position1 as soon as it is done by Icon1.

I know that one way of achieving this to hard code the Icon details(or Icon thread ids) inside Position's acquire() and then compare/write a logic to wait() and notify() the Icon threads.

I am looking for an alternative in which acquire() method is flexible ie., it does n't compare any Icon details, rather it should simply signal or send an event that it is done with Position1 to the following Icons (if any) as soon as Position1 is acquired by Icon1 i.e., I wanted Icon2 thread listening for Icon1 acquire events, etc..

Could you please help ? If this design is complex, can you suggest a simpler design to achieve this (rather than going for the serial access as my requirement itself is to move multiple icons parallely) ?

Comment: It sounds like you are taking a really simple idea if you used one thread and are making it really complicated.  This will be undoubtedly slower, error prone and harder to understand no matter what you do.

Comment: Sounds like an overly complex design to me.    Try an in-memory queue (not a JMS queue) and producer/consumer pattern with executors.  When a Customer adds a Product to the queue, a consumer on the other end will pick it up and process it in the order in which they arrive.  Multi-threaded code is hard to write, even for smart people.  Do yourself a favor and simplify.

Comment: which version of java are you using? Because if you are using java 8, I would recommend `CompleteableFuture` to do this

Comment: I dont see eiter why you want to use concurrency here when the customers have to order one after the other...

Comment: And just for the record: why does a Product has an *order* method? Products are products; and some system *around* them should know which products can be ordered (by knowing about quantities and such things). So I think you should step back even further and have talk to some more people to review the overall system context.

Comment: All: As the customer requests come concurrently, the customer2 SHOULD NOT wait for customer1 completing all product orders.

Comment: @Ash: We are using Java8

Comment: @PeterLawrey: Do you mean this ? List<Customer> customers = new ArrayList<>(); //add customers
  for(Customer customer : customers) {
   customer.start();
  } I don't know how this meets my requirement.

Comment: @javaguy you allocate everything for one Customer and then another in turn. Because it's simple with little over head it's likely to be much faster than doing the same thing with multiple threads.

Comment: @PeterLawrey: I got your point, but mine is actually a gaming application and I have updated my query as above. I changed my actual code to Customer & Product (previous code) as I thought that would be simple to understand,  but apologies for the confusion. So, I can't use the serialized access as I wanted to move multiple Icons at the same time (according to the requirement). i.e., If I need to go for concurrency for sure, can you provide the pseudo code ?

Comment: @duffymo: I have got your point, could you please check my previous comment (to PeterLawrey) and provide the pseudo code ?

Comment: "pseudo code"?  No.  This is your problem, not mine.  You are over complicating it.  Do the simple thing, measure, and change as needed if the performance doesn't meet your requirements.  Simple is better.

Comment: @duffymo: My requirement itself is to move multiple icons at the same time to different locations.

Comment: @javaguy - do it sequentially.  no threads.

Comment: @javaguy your single threaded GUI can only move one Icon at a time. If you are not talking about a GUI application, can you say what you moving concurrently?

Answer (score 0):

Note:  the following answer is based on your original code.  A separate Position class is not required.

To deal with the Customers in order, the program must know the order of the Customers.  I'd suggest that when you create the Customers, you put them in a synchronized List to track their priority.  The List is synchronized because it needs to be thread safe.

Each Product will need to track which Customers have already ordered the Product, so it knows what orders are legitimate.  One way to do this is to have a volatile field containing the most recent Customer to order the Product.  The field is volatile for thread safety.

Replace the call to order() with call to an unsynchronized prepareToOrder() method.  The prepareToOrder() method checks whether the most recent Customer to order the Product is the the Customer that precedes the calling Customer in the Customer priority list.  If it is, then the order() method is called.  If not, it waits and loops back to the check on the most recent Customer.

The order() method remains synchronized, and in addition to its existing functionality, updates the most recent Customer to order the Product.

There are various optimizations that are possible beyond that, depending on your exact requirements, but that should get you going.